# Python 3 determine which part of "or" operation was true

Tags: python

I have a functioning piece of code that suits my purposes but I wasn't sure if there was a better way to meet the end I am looking for. Here is my code :

```
def eitherOne(image1, image2):
    curIm1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image1)
    curIm2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image2)
    while curIm1 == None or curIm2 == None:
        curIm1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image1)
        curIm2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image2)
    if curIm1 != None:
        x, y = pyautogui.center(curIm1)
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
    if curIm2 != None:
        x, y = pyautogui.center(curIm2)
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

What this is doing is looking for one of two images and then clicking on whichever ends up being true. Is there any method or function I can use that can determine which of the conditions around the "or" returned true without running a subsequent set of "if" operations? Even if the answer is "No, you need the if statements" I'd appreciate it so I am not going on a wild goose chase for no reason.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you do need some kind of *secondary structure* that is going to go in and look which of the tested conditions were actually `True`. The thing with your code that is weird is that if for example `curIm2 = None` you will try updating `curIm1` too. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Your current logic requires that *both* `curIm1` and `curIm2` not be `None` before the loop will end, so neither of your `if` statements afterwards are necessary. Do you mean for the `while` to use an `and`, so that it only loops while they're both `None`?

Comment: Assuming exactly one of them is there, you can do `theRightImage = curImg1 or curImg2`.

Comment: BTW, after `while curIm1 == None or curIm2 == None`, shouldn't _both_ images be guaranteed to be non-None?

Comment: @tobias_k , The situation may provide either image, not both. It is an inconsistency with the platform I am working with that I am trying to work around.

Comment: @ToddLewden I understand that from your question, but your `while` loop, in its current form, will continue looping until _both_ are `!= None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this. You create an infinite loop that repeatedly tries one image, then the other, breaking once one of them suceeds.

```
def eitherOne(image1, image2):
    images = itertools.cycle([image1, image2])
    for img in images:
        curIm = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img)
        if curIm is not None:
            break
    x, y = pyautogui.center(curIm)
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

If you prefer a `while` loop to a `for` loop,

```
def eitherOne(image1, image2):
    images = itertools.cycle([image1, image2])
    curIm = None
    while curIm is None:
        curIm = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(next(images))
    x, y = pyautogui.center(curIm)
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

Or, you can do more with `itertools` to avoid an explicit loop altogether.

```
from itertools import cycle, imap, dropwhile

def eitherOne(image1, image2):
    curIm = next(dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, 
                           imap(pyautogui.locateOnScreen,
                                cycle([image1, image2]))))
    x, y = pyautogui.center(curIm)
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

(I'm mildly surprised you can't use `None` as the predicate to `dropwhile`, similar to how you can with `filterfalse`.)

---

Update: actually, since `filter` and `map` already return iterators in Python 3, there's no need to use `dropwhile` and `imap`:

```
def eitherOne(image1, image2):
    curIm = next(filter(None,
                        map(pyautogui.locateOnScreen,
                            cycle([image1, image2]))))
    x, y = pyautogui.center(curIm)
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

---

Bonus content!

To take the functional approach to an extreme, you could write the following in [coconut](http://coconut-lang.org):

```
def eitherOne(image1, image2) = ([images1, images2] |>
                                 cycle |> 
                                 map$(pyautogui.locateOnScreen) |>
                                 filter$(None) |>
                                 next |>
                                 pyautogui.center |*>
                                 pyautogui.click)
```

Answer (score 1):

A v2.7 example of @tobias_k's comment to your question.  In [Boolean Operation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)s, the *value* of the `True` espresion is returned.

```
class Img(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __bool__(self):
        return True

c1 = Img('c1')
c2 = None

current_image = c2 or c1
if current_image:
    print(current_image.name)
else:
    print('None')
```

In this example, `c1` is assigned to `current_image` because it evaluates to `True` and its `name` is printed.